# Session в node.js и express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, сессия

Делаю тестовый проект, back на node.js, express, sequalize. БД Postgresql. Не могу использовать сессии, для сохранения логов пользователя, а это необходимо для того, чтобы корзина создавалась для пользователя сразу. Сейчас это работает, если в запрос конкретно передать userId. Помогите пожалуйста, я уже не понимаю, как мне продолжать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)